# Getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when traversing through json file

Tags: python, json

I am getting this error when i try to get values from a json file in python. I know its a very simple mistake that i am not able to figure out. here is my code:

json response

```
{'responseCode': 0, 'responseDesc': {'booking_date_utc': None, 'city_id': 6, 'city_name': 'Hyderabad', 'start_date': None, 'trip_id': 1, 'trip_name': 'custom-trip-name', 'user_id': 1}}
```

```
if res['responseCode'] == 0:
    for i in res['responseDesc']:
        city_info = 'Your Booking Details:\n Booking Date: {},\n City Name: {},\n Travel Date:{},\n Trip Name: {}'.format(i.get('booking_date_utc'), i.get('city_name'), i.get('start_date'), i.get('trip_name'))
        print(city_info)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need a loop for that. Change `for i in res['responseDesc']:` to `i = res['responseDesc']`.

Comment: @Selcuk, thanks for the help. Could you pls explain why dont we need the loop for iterating through the values

Comment: Because you only have one dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a dictionary like this, the iterator `i` is actually representing the keys. See the sample code below:

```
res = {'responseCode': 0,
       'responseDesc': {'booking_date_utc': None, 'city_id': 6, 'city_name': 'Hyderabad', 'start_date': None,
                        'trip_id': 1, 'trip_name': 'custom-trip-name', 'user_id': 1}}
if res['responseCode'] == 0:
    for i in res['responseDesc']:
        print(i)
# Output:
booking_date_utc
city_id
city_name
start_date
trip_id
trip_name
user_id
```

Also, your res object is actually a dictionary and not a json. Although python dictionaries look a lot like json, they are different things. You can identify it as a dictionary, due to the `None` value, json doesn't know None, but uses `null` for empty values.

So back to your question: when trying to call i.get("booking_date_utc"), you actually try to do this: `"booking_date_utc".get("booking_date_utc")`, because `i` is already the key.

Finally, what you want to do is drop the loop and just access the keys, like suggested in the comments already.